# Determinant is $1$ if the matrix has its transpose as its inverse. PROOF

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

We say that a square matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is unitary if its inverse is given by its transpose. Show that, for a unitary matrix, one has that $\det A = \pm 1$.

I would like to focus on the info given here =and not drift away into explications that are beyond my level. How, from knowing that the transpose is the inverse can we prove that $|\det A|=1$

I tried the inverse=the transpose with $a, b, c, d$ as my numbers and I tried to match up each term with their corresponding one on the other side and =then solve the equation

Comment: What do you know about determinants? Do you know that $\det(A^T) = \det(A)$? And that $\det(A^{-1})\det(A) = 1$?

Comment: so I tried the inverse=the transpose with a b c d as my numbers and I tried to match up each term with their corresponding one on the other side and =then solve the equation

Comment: @mrnobody That's not such a useful approach if the matrix is $3\times 3$ or bigger.

Comment: always try to include your attempts and thoughts when you post a question if possible. and yup, mathjax is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Ingredients:

- What is the definition of inverse? Write it down.
- $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$
- $\det(A)=\det(A^T)$
- $\det(I)=1$

Comment: GOT ITTT thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$$\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$$