# If $A$ is nonsingular matrix such that $A^T=A^{-1}$, then $|A|=1$ (T/F)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is nonsingular matrix such that $A^T=A^{-1}$, then $|A|=1$ (T/F)?

I am not sure if this statement is true or false. All i have got is:

$A^T=A^{-1}$

$A^T= \dfrac{adj (A)}{|A|}$

$|A|=adj (A)/A^T$

.......

What would be the next step?

Comment: Can you express $|A^T|$ in terms of $|A|$?

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2659868/determinant-is-1-if-the-matrix-has-its-transpose-as-its-inverse-proof)

Answer (score 4):

$$
A^T = A^{-1} \\
AA^T=AA^{-1}=I \\
1 = \det(I) = \det(AA^{-1})=\det(AA^T)=\det(A)\det(A^T)={\det(A)}^2
$$
Therefore...

Comment: I am not sure what you did. What happened to A inverse?

Comment: I shuffled the equalities to maybe make it more obvious — feel feee to revert if you don’t prefer that. +1

Comment: @SaraRafiq multiply both sides of 1st eqn. by A